# Combine 2 classes with adding data and 1 table has a colllection list of the other table and wanting to use linq to display

Tags: c#, linq, list, generics, collections

I have 2 poco classes in which I am wanting to property mock the data and then end up with using the 2nd table as a subset collection of data

Two classes which represents tables in **sql** , the **ReportGroupId** is **primary** key in **ReportGroup** and **foreign** key in **ReportDefinition**

```
public class ReportData
{
    public List<ReportDefinition> items {get; set;} 

    public int ReportGroupId { get; set; }
    public string ReportGroupName { get; set; }
    public int SortOrder { get; set; }
    public int Type { get; set; }

}

public class ReportDefinition
{

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ReportGroupNameDef { get; set; }
    public int SortOrder { get; set; }
    public int ReportGroupId { get; set; }
    public int Type { get; set; }
}
```

Then I **hydrate** the **class properties**

```
List<ReportDefinition> reportDefinition = new List<ReportDefinition>();
    reportDefinition.Add(new ReportDefinition() {Id = 5, ReportGroupNameDef = "Web Usuage", SortOrder = 1, ReportGroupId = 1, Type = 2});
    reportDefinition.Add(new ReportDefinition() {Id = 6, ReportGroupNameDef = "Compliance Report", SortOrder = 1, ReportGroupId = 2, Type = 2});

List<ReportData> reportData = new List<ReportData>();
    reportData.Add(new ReportData() {ReportGroupId = 1, ReportGroupName = "Standard Report", SortOrder = 1, Type = 2});
    reportData.Add(new ReportData() {ReportGroupId = 2, ReportGroupName = "Custom Report", SortOrder = 2, Type = 2});
```

Next what I am hoping for is to essentially have a joining of the 2 tables of which my end goal is output as JSON

I'm having trouble with figuring out how to populate **items** of which is a generic list collection in **ReportData** class that represents the **ReportDefinition**

This is what I was doing with **LINQ**

```
var query = from rd in reportData
                //join rg in reportDefinition on rd.ReportGroupId equals rg.ReportGroupId
                //select rd;
                select new
                {
                    rd.ReportGroupName,
                    rd.items,
                    rd.ReportGroupId

                };

    string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(query);

    output.Dump();
```

Here is a DotNetFiddle  https://dotnetfiddle.net/IIBFKG

Ok the is solved, but I have to wait 90 minutes to ask another question ughh

So my real data is buried in a .net mvc project with repository and Unit of work patterns

Basically I want to end up doing the same thing as what this data is doing except a lot of things are abstracted away from me , using entity framework , but I suppose i should be able to still use a Linq query right?

This is what I was putting together

```
var reportGroups = _envyUnitOfWork.ReportGroupsAll.GetAll().ToList();
        var reportDefinition = _envyUnitOfWork.ReportDefinitions.GetAll().ToList();



        List<ReportGroupItem> reportGroupItems = new List<ReportGroupItem>();
        foreach (ReportGroup reportGroup in reportGroups)
        {
            reportGroupItems.Add(new ReportGroupItem() {Id = reportGroup.Id, ReportGroupName = reportGroup.ReportGroupName, SortOrder = reportGroup.SortOrder, Type = 1});

        } 



        // need to query reportdefinitions and add to items of reportGroupItems
        // List<ReportDefinition>


        return _envyUnitOfWork.ReportGroupsAll.GetAll().ToList();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put all reportDefinitions in groups and `Join` reportData with them

```
var reports = reportDefinition.GroupBy(r=>r.ReportGroupId);
var query = reportData.Join(reports, d => d.ReportGroupId, gr => gr.Key, 
                                    (r,gr) => new
                                    {
                                      r.ReportGroupName,
                                      items = gr.ToList(),
                                      r.ReportGroupId
                                    });
```

JSON

> [{"ReportGroupName":"Standard Report","items":[{"Id":5,"ReportGroupNameDef":"Web Usuage","SortOrder":1,"ReportGroupId":1,"Type":2}],"ReportGroupId":1},{"ReportGroupName":"Custom Report","items":[{"Id":6,"ReportGroupNameDef":"Compliance Report","SortOrder":1,"ReportGroupId":2,"Type":2}],"ReportGroupId":2}]

Comment: do i need to change to classes or how i'm adding data,  or just use this query?

Comment: @MillRunner, it should simply work if you replace `var query = ...;` part

Comment: I have to wait to add another question.  I ended up just putting my question with my code as a edit to the question at the bottom ... Starts with "Ok the is solved"    -  If you have any feedback on that, i greatly appreciate it

Comment: @MillRunner, i took a look but did't understand how ReportGroupItem is related with ReportData and ReportDefinition and what result is expected

Comment: I had copied that ,   ReportGroupItem is identical to ReportData...  sorry about that .     It was simply a  SRP , with the data access layer vs. business layer .

Comment: I added a question    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36207202/data-in-linq-query-not-in-join-is-not-in-output-to-json-only-those-that-are-rela      thx