# Data in Linq query not in join is not in output to json only those that are related in 2 classes are showing up

Tags: c#, json, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

The basis of this question is from this question:

[Combine 2 classes with adding data and 1 table has a colllection list of the other table and wanting to use linq to display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36195360/combine-2-classes-with-adding-data-and-1-table-has-a-colllection-list-of-the-oth)

In which I "thought" the problem was solved.

However as I added in a new object to the List, now this join query does not output it

```
reportData.Add(new ReportData() {ReportGroupId = 3, ReportGroupName = "Straggler", SortOrder = 3, Type = 1});


var reports = reportDefinition.GroupBy(r=>r.ReportGroupId);
    var query = reportData.Join(reports, d => d.ReportGroupId, gr => gr.Key, 
                                (r,gr) => new
                                {
                                  r.ReportGroupName,
                                  items = gr.ToList(),
                                  r.ReportGroupId
                                });
```

Here is the dotNetFiddle   https://dotnetfiddle.net/IIBFKG

Why doesn't the item that I added to the ReportData not show up?  Is it the type of JOIN in Linq?

Comment: Because you are performing `inner join`, and there is no `Report` with `ReportGroupId = 3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the linked question was not answered correctly.

Looks like all you need is a simple [Group Join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311040.aspx):

```
var query = 
    from d in reportData
    join r in reportDefinition on d.ReportGroupId equals r.ReportGroupId into items
    select new
    {
        d.ReportGroupName,
        items = items.ToList(),
        d.ReportGroupId
    };
```

Comment: Nice!  Thank you so much Ivan

Comment: , any chance you can look at this    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36209508/adding-a-3rd-class-in-which-2-classes-are-subitems-for-linq-query-to-end-up-disp