# Adding a 3rd class in which 2 classes are subitems for linq query to end up displaying to json

Tags: c#, json, linq

This question is based on

[Data in Linq query not in join is not in output to json only those that are related in 2 classes are showing up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36207202/data-in-linq-query-not-in-join-is-not-in-output-to-json-only-those-that-are-rela/36207736#36207736)

in which this answer DID work fine

However, I'm adding a 3rd class that i want to group into "items"

```
var query = 
from d in reportData
join r in reportDefinition on d.ReportGroupId equals r.ReportGroupId into items
select new
{
    d.ReportGroupName,
    items = items.ToList(),
    d.ReportGroupId
};
```

New updated dotnetfiddle https://dotnetfiddle.net/IIBFKG

How do I ADD in CustomReportDefinition class to get displayed in the items or ReportData?

Comment: Let me see if I understand the question. Instead of items being `List<ReportDefinition` you want them to be `List<CustomReportDefinition>`? i.e. converting `ReportDefinition` to `CustomReportDefinition`?

Comment: Or you want another join and something like `new { ..., items = items.ToList(), customItems = ... }`?

Comment: @IvanStoev    Sorry for the delay in responding,  had a meeting to go to.   YES the 2nd comment ,   another join

Comment: Your [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/IIBFKG) is confusing.  You allocate `List<CustomReportDefinition> customReportDefinition = new List<CustomReportDefinition>();` but then never add to it, instead you add to the `reportDefinition` list twice.  Is that a mistake?

Comment: @IvanStoev    So I was wondering if I should have a 4th class in which this new class would actually have both collection of ReportDefinition and CustomReportDefinition  ...

Comment: @dbc   Sorry about that,  fixed the fiddle

Comment: So in the end I want to have the "items" contain both ReportDefinitions AND CustomReportDefinition

Comment: Could you post that 4th class definition? I guess it will be used instead of the anonymous type.

Comment: @IvanStoev   I didn't create a 4th class,  I'm just wondering if that is the best way to handle this situation....    So what if the business team decides they want another database table that is like Another Custom Report Definition ,,   and then I create a Poco class to represent that , and say it is also mapped then to the main class  ReportData ,  does it make sense to have a 4th table to handle 1 to many collections ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you can add as many similar classes as you wish using exactly the same pattern:

```
var query = from d in reportData
            join r in reportDefinition on d.ReportGroupId equals r.ReportGroupId into items
            join cr in customReportDefinition on d.ReportGroupId equals cr.ReportGroupId into customItems
            select new
            {
                d.ReportGroupName,
                items = items.ToList(),
                customItems = customItems.ToList(),
                d.ReportGroupId
            };
```

**UPDATE:** Base on your comments, looks like you want to consolidate `items` and `customItems`. See if the following works for you:

```
var query = from d in reportData
            join r in reportDefinition on d.ReportGroupId equals r.ReportGroupId into items
            join cr in customReportDefinition on d.ReportGroupId equals cr.ReportGroupId into customItems
            select new
            {
                d.ReportGroupName,
                items = items.Select(r => new
                {
                    r.Id, r.ReportGroupNameDef, r.SortOrder, r.ReportGroupId, r.Type
                }).Concat(customItems.Select(cr => new
                {
                    cr.Id, cr.ReportGroupNameDef, cr.SortOrder, cr.ReportGroupId, cr.Type
                })).ToList(),
                d.ReportGroupId
            };
```

Comment: Ok, so I need to ONLY have "items" because of the end data ends up exporting as JSON to a Kendo TreeView and it expects all children to be defined in the items

Comment: I'm not understanding your last comment.  Is what you are saying what I want?

Comment: Ah, so what it should be? We can concatenate the results, but need a common type. Or use one of the existing types (`ReportDefinition` for instance) and convert the other - they seem to have one and the same fields.

Comment: item = item.ToList()    --> this needs to represent both ReportDefinition AND CustomReportDefinition

Comment: Probably I misunderstood your idea for the 4th class.

Comment: I really appreciate your help on this Ivan.   So would it be best to have a separate Linq query that concatenates the 2 classes of data together ?

Comment: @MillRunner There is no problem to concatenate them with one query, we need just a common class (or convert one class to another)

Comment: Ok,  so I guess a 4th class could be used , but does it help ,  or should there be an additional linq query?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107279/discussion-between-ivan-stoev-and-millrunner).

Comment: Ok, If i place into the fiddle, i get an error on line 86